# Very mysterious runtime error: Bad type operand on stack

Tags: jvm, kotlin

I get this very mysterious error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/bh/tools/base/strings/TestUtils.concat(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/CharSequence; @28: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/String'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @28
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/CharSequence' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/StringBuilder', 'java/lang/Object' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a12 59b8 0012 2b12 43b8 0012 2ac1 005b
    0x0000010: 9900 1a2a bb00 1659 b700 1a5f b600 512b
    0x0000020: b600 5eb6 0052 c000 23b0 2ac1 0016 9900
    0x0000030: 152a c000 162b b600 5e59 1260 b800 63c0
    0x0000040: 0023 b0bb 0016 59b7 001a 2ab6 0047 2bb6
    0x0000050: 005e 5912 65b8 0063 c000 23b0          
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@42)
    same_frame(@67)


    at org.bh.tools.base.math.NumberConversionKtTestKt.assertNumbersClose(NumberConversionKtTest.kt:488)
    at org.bh.tools.base.math.NumberConversionKtTest.Number_float32Value(NumberConversionKtTest.kt:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:58)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

At this line:
https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Base/blob/ea415b702b87b7a33d90bc13221f44205c38e9f1/JVM/test/org/bh/tools/base/math/NumberConversionKtTest.kt#L488

I think it involves this function:
https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Base/blob/ea415b702b87b7a33d90bc13221f44205c38e9f1/JVM/src/org/bh/tools/base/strings/String%20Utils.kt#L121-L154

but I can't possibly understand what's going wrong. It seems to indicate that I'm calling a concatenate method on an `Object` and a `CharSequence` within the `TestUtils` class (which I don't think is touched when I run [the test that triggers this](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Base/blob/ea415b702b87b7a33d90bc13221f44205c38e9f1/JVM/test/org/bh/tools/base/math/NumberConversionKtTest.kt#L42-L52)), but sounds mighty close to [another function I wrote](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Base/blob/ea415b702b87b7a33d90bc13221f44205c38e9f1/JVM/src/org/bh/tools/base/strings/String%20Utils.kt#L64-L76) which wasn't used here.

**Something's going on that I cannot get my head around. Does anyone have any ideas?**

---

### Companion JetBrains bug: [KT-17210](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Dmitry Petrov](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17210#comment=27-2099281) and [Alexander Chernikov](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17210#comment=27-2099291), this is a compiler bug in Kotlin 1.1.1, which has been fixed in the 1.1.2 release.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the bytecode to study, all of the below explaination are built on one assumption: the Kotlin has smart cast wrong once again.

### tl;dr  JVM verify the whole class instead of just the proportion used.

The situation happens in the below steps:

1. Test ran. Junit found tests and tried to invoke `org.bh.tools.base.math.NumberConversionKtTest::Number_float32Value` reflection. This triggered the loading, linking and initialization of class `NumberConversionKtTest`. Everything is good.
2. This method invoked `org.bh.tools.base.math.NumberConversionKtTestKt.assertNumbersClose`, which is inside a class not yet loaded (note the trialing `Kt` which the previous class does not has). JVM found, loaded, linked and initialized it.
3. The `assertNumbersClose` is now being executed, i.e. a new frame is created and pushed into the stack. After executing some of bytecode, the program flow moved to line 488, and found a method invocation instruction, which asks the JVM to execute a method lying in the class `org.bh.tools.base.strings.TestUtils`. This class hadn't yet beening loaded, so the JVM started loading a new class.
4. JVM loads that class, and, during [verifying](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.1), it found the method `concat`, not the one used in `assertNumbersClose`, is not good. It stops verifying with a `VerifyError`. Because the method `differingCharacters` hadn't yet been executed, i.e. no new frame was created and pushed into the stack, it's not on the stacktrace, so you see `org.bh.tools.base.math.NumberConversionKtTestKt.assertNumbersClose` on the top.

---

### Posible workaround

You need to fix the `concat` method's bytecode, somehow. You have these following wrokaround.

1. Try upgrade kotlin compiler. I recall some smartcast related issues being fixed in the kotlin 1.1.
2. Since this error is kotlin compiler failing to emit a CHECKCAST for smartcasts, you may trying adding a manual cast, like this:

   ```
   fun concat(lhs: Any, rhs: CharSequence): CharSequence {
       if (lhs is String) {
           val s: String = lhs as String
           return s.plus(rhs)
       } else if (lhs is StringBuilder) {
           val sb: StringBuilder= lhs as StringBuilder
           return sb.append(rhs)
       } else {
           return StringBuilder().append(lhs).append(rhs)
       }
   }
   ```

   This **sometimes** works for **some** people.
3. If all of these don't work, Switch to plain Java and place `concat` in another class. This fixes most, if not all, kotlin issues.

Comment: Wow, you seem to be right on the money! I changed the function as described and now it runs just fine! I filed a bug with JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17210

Comment: It will be useful if you also submitted the deassembled bytecode to JetBrains. You can get these info by using javap, a java bytecode deassembler shipped in JDK distributions. (To be frank I should be able to do this, but I don't know how to make javap work with only method bytecode, which is included in the exception message, instead of the full classfile)